# Flexible API Limits—Question

Tags: batch, limits, schedulebatch

Please can someone confirm the following about Flexible API limits:

Provides the ability for me to queue up more than (5) batch jobs for processing.

Only (5) jobs are executing at any one time and as slot frees up, the queued batch jobs would get executed.

Want to avoid this one

> Scheduled job 'SWD_SoftwareDownloads - Hourly' threw unhandled exception.
>   caused by: System.LimitException: Attempted to schedule too many concurrent batch jobs in this org (limit is 5).